# Fragment methods duplicating on each presenter call

Tags: android, mvp, rx-java2

I am developing an Andoid weather application and encountered a problem. In the drawer i have several cities and when i select one of those Presenter method after successful request calling view methods updateWeather..., if error - showError called. But the problem is than when i got the weather for one city (one fragment) and than i choose another fragment(another city) from drawer, view methods updateWeather or showError called many times (to be exact - as many times as i was switching fragments).

In onActivityCReated i call method presenter.getWeather()

Presenter have this code

```
void getWeather() {
        Log.i("WeatherPresenter", "StartLoading");
        getViewState().showLoading();
        dataSubscription = repository.getWeatherData()
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(next -> {
                            Log.i("LoadWeather", "Success");
                            getViewState().hideLoading();
                            getViewState().updateWeatherCurrent(next.getWeatherResponse());
                            getViewState().updateWeatherHourly(next.getWeatherForecastHourlyResponse());
                            getViewState().updateWeatherDaily(next.getWeatherForecastDailyResponse());
                            getViewState().updateLastUpdateTime(dateFormat.format(new Date(next.getUpdatedTime())));
                        },
                        error -> {
                            getViewState().hideLoading();
                            Log.e("Error", error.getMessage());
                            getViewState().showError();
                        });
    }
```

From the logs if error occurred method getViewState().showError(); called only once. But in the fragment it is calling as many times as i was switching fragments.

This is logs - to understand what i mean

```
08-08 16:35:42.738 31682-31682/dvinc.yamblzhomeproject E/WeatherFragment: Error Shown
08-08 16:35:42.913 31682-31682/dvinc.yamblzhomeproject E/Error: Unable to resolve host "api.openweathermap.org": No address associated with hostname
08-08 16:35:42.914 31682-31682/dvinc.yamblzhomeproject E/WeatherFragment: Error Shown
```

In presenter i unsubscribe from request

```
@Override
    public void detachView(WeatherView view) {
        super.detachView(view);
        Log.i("WeatherPresenter", "DetachView");
        if (dataSubscription != null) {
            dataSubscription.dispose();
        }
    }
```

And this is how i switch fragments

```
@Override
public void showFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.fragmentContainer, fragment)
            .commit();
}
```

Here is how i call this method from main presenter (responsible for navigation)

```
void openWeatherFragment(CityEntity cityEntity) {
        menuActiveCity = menuRepository.setActiveCity(cityEntity)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe();

        getViewState().showFragment(WeatherFragment.newInstanse(cityEntity.getCityTitle()));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. The problem was because I marked all my presenters with a singleton annotations, but forgot about the way how Moxy organising it is own injection of presenters.